# Flutter: Unable to display image in preview when image is shared Whatsapp and Facebook

Tags: android, image, android-intent, dart, flutter

The image is able to show in Facebook Messenger chat, however the image is unable to be displayed in Whatsapp as well as the preview image for both messenger and whatsapp. Any idea where I did wrong?

**Main.dart** - This is where I capture my image and save it to a temporary directory.

```
  RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = globalKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
  var image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: 3.0);
  ByteData byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png);
  Uint8List pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();

  final tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
  final file = await new File('${tempDir.path}/image.png').create();
  await file.writeAsBytes(pngBytes);

  final channel = const MethodChannel('channel:me.amanda.share/share');
  channel.invokeMethod('shareFile', 'image.png');
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
private void shareFile(String path) {

try{
     File imageFile = new File(this.getCacheDir(), path);
     Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "me.amanda.share", 
     imageFile);
     Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
     shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
     shareIntent.setData(contentUri);
     shareIntent.setType("image/png");

     shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri);
     this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share image 
     using"));
     }
     catch (Exception ex){
        //android.widget.Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage(), 
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
  }
```

**file_path.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <paths>
    <cache-path name="image" path="."/>
    </paths>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, this is a very silly mistake. The image is a QR code where the background of the QR code is transparent. Hence, I should wrap the qr image into a Container() widget and set the container to white where the RepaintBoundary can capture the entire container with the QR code. I didn't notice well that the preview image and messenger is dark.

This is an example.

```
    hasValue ? Container(
    height: 230.0,
    color: Colors.white,
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
    child: Center(
      child: RepaintBoundary(
        key: globalKey,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: QrImage(
            data: !isScan ? _dataBarcodeString : trimBarcodeValue,
            size: 200.0,
          ),
        )
      ),
    ),
```